# Combinatorics picture problem

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 teachers and 100 students.

1. How many ways can a picture be taken with 5 teachers and 20 students?
2. Now the picture will be taken with 8 teachers and 30 students. The picture will be 8 teachers THEN 30 students. How many ways can it be taken?

Solutions: These were the solutions that were given for my worksheet. I am a little confused as to why these are the correct answers and would appreciate an explanation of both.

1. $\binom{10}{5} \cdot \binom{100}{20} \cdot 25!$
2. $P(10, 8) \cdot P(100, 30)$

Why is solution #2 using r-permutation instead of r-combination? I don't really understand how that would put 8 teachers first and then 30 students after?

Comment: Observe that $P(10, 8) = \binom{10}{8} \cdot 8!$ and that $P(100, 30) = \binom{100}{30} \cdot 30!$.

Comment: Notice ${n \choose k}=$ ways to choice without regard to order.  $k! $ equals way to order.  $P (n,8) =$ ways to choose with regard to order.  So logically $P (n,k) $=ways to choice with order = ${n \choose k}k!$=ways to choose without order times ways to order.  Now the question assumes it's obvious that "ways to take a picture" means ways to choose AND order people.  So in the first question it is "how many ways to choose 5 teachers, 20 students, and how many ways to arrange 25 people.The second is how many ways to choose and arrange 8 teachers.Then choose and arrange 30 students.

Comment: To be honest it never would have occured to me "number of ways to take picture" would have included how many ways to order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: in first case we take 5 teachers from 10 and 20 students from 100 and arrange all 25 of them in 25 positions.
In second one. It says u Chose 8 teachers and arrange them. simple permutations. And THEN consider removing all 8 of them and chose 30 students and arrange them on 30 chairs.
Hope it helps